# Python 2 code not working with Python 3 can't solve

Tags: logging, python-2to3

i'm upgrading an old python 2 program and have been having so much trouble upgrading the code and everything but i've been able to get by thanks to the docs, but i can't figure this one out.

Its a very simple function but i keep getting weird errors i never got in python2, here is the code:

```
def log(self, message):
    print("[SYSTEM][{0}]".format(datetime.strftime(time.gmtime()+message, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))
```

Now the error i get is this:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple
```

Here is how it should look outputted to the console:

```
[SYSTEM][2020-06-04 17:30:51]MessageHere
```

Any help would be appreciated as this has been driving me nuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixing your original method:

```py
def log(self, message):
    print("[SYSTEM][{0}]".format(datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')) + message)
```

A bit cleaner version using [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/):

```py
def log(self, message):
    print(f"[SYSTEM][{datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}]{message}")
```